# Is it possible in luigi Python to use database row as Output

Tags: python, luigi

I am learning luigi and see that mostly the output is file on filesystem.

If that file exists then luigi think that task is done.

In my case instead of writing file i want to update databas erecord with status `DONE` in postgres.

I want to know that is it possible in luigi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Luigi contribs](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/tree/master/luigi/contrib). There are at least 3 packages there you can be interested in: `mssqldb`, `mysqldb`, `rdbms`, `sqla` and `redshift`. If you open any of them, look for `luigi.Target` subclasses.

By instance, in `luigi.contribs.mysqldb` you have `MySqlTarget`. It gives you a functionality like the one you talk about above: the task checks that the "marker table" exists (if not, this task will create it), and then makes a select to check if the task has been already executed successfully. If not, it inserts a "marker" for the task saying it's DONE.

If you already have a "marker table" you can subclass this task class or create a similar one by copying its code and customizing the parts you need or don't need.